# Debugging Swing App

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, debugging

Hello I am wondering if it is possible to debug a Java Swing Application without going inside of the JComponent class to create JPanel,Jbuttons,ect. I am really only concerned with debugging my code, and not looking into how the creation of the JPanels,JButtons,ect.

I have set breakpoints in my code on variables that I have created, and want to see how they are behaving, but when trying to run debug mode it starts in the main method as if there is a break point when one is not present.

I have attached where the break point actually is in my code.
[where I have inserted my breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJFfE.png)

[image]

and this is where the debugger starts when I attempt to debug the class.
[where the debugger starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h33E2.png)

[image]

**EDIT**
I have attached my code below.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class main_frame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // Panels
    private JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    private JPanel inPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel outPanel = new JPanel();

    // Labels
    private JLabel lblFile;
    private final JLabel lblInformation = new JLabel(
            "<html>Please select a Directory  or File that you would like to keep an eye on.Once you have selected your directory or file, hit the submit button to start and set your alert time.</html> ");

    // textFields
    private JTextField file_path = new JTextField();
    private JTextField txtAlerttime;
    // tables
    private JTable filesAndTimes = new JTable();

    // JScrollPane
    private JScrollPane scroll;

    // Buttons
    private JButton btnCancel = new JButton();
    private JButton btnOpen = new JButton();
    private JButton btnSubmit = new JButton();

    // Other Variables
    File file = null;
    String[] fileNames = null;
    String[] fileTimes = null;
    String[] filePaths = null;
    int submit_count = 0;
    int openEventClickCount = 0;

    /**
     * Create the main frame.
     */
    public main_frame() {
        gui();
    }

    /*
     * @param The gui that is going to create the main frame for our
     * application.
     */
    public void gui() {
        setTitle("File Watcher 2000");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 863, 480);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        inPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
        inPanel.setBounds(217, 12, 634, 163);
        inPanel.setLayout(null);
        contentPane.add(inPanel);

        lblFile = new JLabel("Select File or Directory :");
        lblFile.setBounds(12, 56, 177, 17);
        inPanel.add(lblFile);

        file_path.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
        file_path.setBounds(207, 54, 243, 19);
        file_path.setColumns(20);
        file_path.setEditable(false);
        inPanel.add(file_path);
        lblInformation.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        lblInformation.setBounds(12, 12, 610, 30);

        inPanel.add(lblInformation);

        JLabel lblAlertMeWhen = new JLabel("Alert me when my File or Directory changes in :");
        lblAlertMeWhen.setBounds(12, 85, 339, 15);
        inPanel.add(lblAlertMeWhen);

        txtAlerttime = new JTextField();
        txtAlerttime.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        txtAlerttime.setText("120");
        txtAlerttime.setBounds(357, 85, 44, 15);
        inPanel.add(txtAlerttime);
        txtAlerttime.setColumns(5);

        JLabel lblMins = new JLabel("mins");
        lblMins.setBounds(407, 85, 44, 15);
        inPanel.add(lblMins);

        // Cancel Event

        btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.setBounds(12, 127, 81, 25);
        inPanel.add(btnCancel);

        // Open Event

        btnOpen = new JButton("Open");
        btnOpen.setBounds(451, 127, 72, 25);
        inPanel.add(btnOpen);

        // Submit Event

        btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        btnSubmit.setBounds(539, 127, 83, 25);
        inPanel.add(btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                mf_submit_Event submitEvent = new mf_submit_Event(file);

                submitEvent.actionPerformed(e);

                fileNames = submitEvent.getFileNames();
                System.out.println("File Times has " + fileNames.length + " files.");

                fileTimes = submitEvent.getFileTimes();
                System.out.println("File Times has " + fileTimes.length + " files.");

                filePaths = submitEvent.getFilePaths();
                System.out.println("File Paths has " + filePaths.length + " files.");

                filesAndTimes = submitEvent.getTable();
                System.out.println("Table Retrieved from Submit Event Successfully");

                scroll = new JScrollPane(filesAndTimes);
                scroll.setBounds(12, 12, 550, 177);
                filesAndTimes.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

                // The mouseHandler Class handles custom events for the JTable
                // through the submit event.
                filesAndTimes.addMouseListener(new submitMouseEventHandler(filesAndTimes));
                submit_count++;

                outPanel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                outPanel.revalidate();
            }
        });

        // ****************** OPEN EVENT ******************************

        btnOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mf_open_Event openEvent = new mf_open_Event();
                // call ActionEvent
                openEvent.actionPerformed(e);

                // Setting the file path that was chosen by the user.
                file = openEvent.getFile();
                openEventClickCount++;
                System.out.println("Open event click count is " + openEventClickCount);
                /*
                 * Setting the text field to be the file chosen by the user, if
                 * no file is chosen, the file path is set to the default root
                 * directory in the users computer.
                 */

                if (isNull(file)) {
                    file_path.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    file_path.setText(File.listRoots()[0].getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        });

        // ****************** CANCEL EVENT ******************************
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int userChoice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                        "Are you sure that you want to Exit the Program", "Close Program",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                if (userChoice == 0) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {

                    int userClearTable = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                            "Would you like to clear the data in the Table?", "Clear Table Data",
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if (userClearTable == 0) {
                        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) filesAndTimes.getModel();
                        dtm.setColumnCount(0);
                        dtm.setRowCount(0);

                        filesAndTimes.setModel(dtm);

                    }
                }

            }
        });
        outPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
        outPanel.setBounds(12, 187, 839, 281);
        contentPane.add(outPanel);
        outPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel("");
        imgLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        imgLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        Image img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/file_icon.png")).getImage();
        imgLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        imgLabel.setBounds(12, 12, 159, 135);
        contentPane.add(imgLabel);

    }// END OF THE GUI

    /*
     * ************************************* METHOD HOUSING BELOW
     * *******************************************
     */

    /**
     * @param checking
     *            that the file parameter that is passed in is not null.
     * @returns true if the parameter is null.
     */
    public boolean isNull(File file) {
        boolean answer = false;
        if (file != null) {
            answer = true;
        }
        return answer;
    }

    /**
     * @param checking
     *            that the string array parameter that is passed in is not null.
     * @returns true if the parameter is null.
     */
    public boolean isNull(String[] strArray) {
        boolean answer = false;
        if (strArray != null) {
            answer = true;
        }
        return answer;
    }

    /**
     * @param checking
     *            that the String parameter that is passed in is not null.
     * @returns true if the parameter is null.
     */
    public boolean isNull(String str) {
        boolean answer = false;
        if (str != null) {
            answer = true;
        }
        return answer;
    }

    /**
     * @param getting
     *            the integer alert time that is passed by the user.
     * @return alert time in minutes
     */
    public int getAlertTime() {
        return Integer.parseInt(txtAlerttime.getText());
    }

    /**
     * @param getting
     *            the file or directory path that was selected by the user.
     * @return file path provided by the user.
     */
    public String getFilePath() {
        return file.getName();
    }

}
```

Comment: Look for the "step over" command

Comment: 1. Show your code here with your question, not in a link. 2. Yes, definitely it's not hard to debug Swing applications, especially if you use good M-V-C (model-view-controller) separation of concerns, and in fact this is one of the main reasons for doing this.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're posting images of code which is even harder to help with since there's no way we can copy and paste your code. Again, please post code as text that has been formatted as code. Your job is to try to make it as easy as possible for others to help you, and this will go a long way towards that goal.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I usually use the "step over" command unless I need to dive into a methods inter workings, but in this case on debugger start up it takes me directly into the JComponent class, when I step over the code all to the end of the my gui creation code it shows nothing in the JFrame.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels please see the edit where I have added my code.

Comment: Signs of a newbie Swing coder: `setLayout(null);` and `inPanel.setBounds(217, 12, 634, 163);`. Why? Because the longer you use Swing, the more you realize that using null layouts and setBounds increases your bugs and work load exponentially. Use the layout managers wisely as this will help you out immensely.

Comment: The main criticism I have of your code, the one that is getting in the way of your debugging, is that your class is huge, but more importantly has too many diverse responsibilities -- it's a "God-class". You need to refactor this beast, subdivide it into constituent classes, again along an MVC structure, and this will make your debugging much easier as well as your program upgradeability.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for your feedback, I will look into the MVC structure further and improve upon this code. Do you have any suggestions regarding the layout managers, or do's and dont's of Swing?

Comment: re layout managers -- read the tut's and experiment with them. The more you use them, the better you'll be with them. Start with simple layout managers, and avoid GridBagLayout to start with. Nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager, allowing for complex GUI's using simple layouts.

Comment: It's possible you have old break points still setup, you might want to see if you can clear all break points and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, go to Window/Preferences/Java/Debug/Step Filtering. Add entries for java.awt.* and javax.swing.*, and turn on step filtering.  Now the debugger will execute methods in these classes as a single step when single stepping. Other IDEs should have similar settings.

When the debugger stops in odd places, it is often because there is another project open that has a different version of the source code. Eclipse does not seem capable of telling what source code belongs to the current binary being debugged. This is particularly a problem if several projects are open that reference different versions of the same library. This is not likely to be your problem, but keep it in mind.

But a slightly off-topic question: Why do you have isNull() methods that return true when the passed parameter is **not** null? Surely they should be renamed isNotNull(), or the test should be negated?

Also those methods can be static one-liners:

```
public static boolean isNotNull(File file) {
     return file != null;
}
```

Even better, just include the test in your code and delete the methods.

Comment: thanks, I actually had them as a test condition in the code previous but was watching an MIT open course ware course where they stated that you should put your test in methods allowing  for modularity, and code re-use. However I am still pretty new to programming in Java, so I appreciate all the feedback.

Comment: also with the solution that you proposed the debugger is still taking me into the JComponent class.

Comment: @Well either javax.swing.* is not in the filter list  or filtering is not enabled